# fruitcake / laravel-cors is rejecting PDF files

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I have PDF files under public directory. and i can access them by visiting the link on the browser, and it works fine.

However when i try to embed the PDF doc in `FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf`  i get:

***CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing***

here is my cors.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

And here is my kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ...
];
```

---

I have also tried removing the whole package and use plain php like so, but it is still not working:

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Accept,charset,boundary,Content-Length');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

---

**EDIT**

[image: error]

attached http request
[image]

Comment: Is it really related to VueJS ?

Comment: I thought someone from the `Vue` community might relate..

Comment: Didn't want to be rude. Was just asking if a CORS issue was somehow related to this Vue package. IMO, it's only a backend issue here. Feel free to leave the [tag:vue] tag here if you feel like it fits. :)

Comment: Could be something to do with the way the package is making requests to the server. i added it because i do not know what's causing the error..

Comment: CORS is usually 99% caused by backend. You could double-check by watching at what is the payload sent by the package in your devtools network tab.

Comment: ok, i've updated my question, i've included the screenshot for the network request

Comment: Looks like this part is not erroring and working great!

Comment: Laravel likely isn't handling that PDF request at all; is it a direct link to a file? If so, you'll have to configure CORS at the webserver level for that `docs` folder.

Comment: @ceejayoz if you mean including the `docs/*` in my `cors.php`.. i tried it and still didn't work

Comment: No, I mean if those are direct links to .pdf files on your server, Laravel and PHP have nothing to do with the request at all; it never gets to them.You'd need to enable CORS at the webserver level for that folder; https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Are you using Apache or nginx

Comment: And is the PDF being stored in public directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason CORS is not working is because none of your PHP code is even being run for static files.

If you are using Apache, and look at the `public/.htaccess` it contains:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [END]
```

If you go on Nginx, and look at the config located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, it should contain:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

In either case, the above basically means that if the request is not a directory or a file within `public` then run the script in `index.php`.

You have a few options:

### Method 1: Adjust the server configs

You can make modifications to your server configs to enable CORS for certain or all static files:

- [All](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)
- [Apache](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)
- [Nginx](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

### Method 2: Serve the file through the application

1. Move the file into somewhere in Storage
2. Create a new route and controller to something like this:

```
Route::get('files/my-example-file.pdf', function () {
    return response()->file($path);
});
```

Remember the path should be absolute like `'/home/vagrant/code/my-project/storage/app/sample.pdf`

Also remember to apply the CORS middle-ware to the route somehow (e.g. through a middleware group).

Now the CORS middleware should run.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but, this project is doing this even on localhost ( `php artisan serve` ), and i'm using Nginx on the live server.

Comment: Then use the 2nd method, and serve the file through the application.

Comment: i have accepted the answer but i still have lot of `?` mark in my mind...

Comment: What are your questions?

Comment: Serve the file trough the application helped me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to store the file on the server

You can add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` before returning the PDF response.
Example with mpdf:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Test send of PDF</h1>');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
return $mpdf->Output("Test.pdf", Destination::INLINE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding this line works for me.

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Answer (score 0):

In my case i follow the link in [Yahya Uddin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67134631/2387051) for [Apache Cors configuration](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) and the only thing i need is to enable Mod_Headers with this command

```
a2enmod headers
```

and restart apache